# How do base and turbo frequencies affect core utilization in multi-core CPUs?

Tags: power, cpu-architecture, cpu-speed, intel, cpufreq

I'm trying to understand the relationship between base and turbo frequencies in multi-core CPUs, specifically regarding core utilization. My CPU has a base frequency of 2.1 GHz and a turbo frequency of 3.0 GHz. I have a couple of questions:

Can all cores operate at 100% usage at the base frequency (2.1 GHz) without exceeding the TDP? In turbo mode (up to 3.0 GHz), does this limit the number of active cores? How does this impact performance and thermal management? Any insights or clarifications on these points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would guess this may depend on specific CPUs. Being able to operate cores at independent frequencies seems a good way to maximize CPU efficiency.

Comment: I think this would be different for different models of cpus and the operating temperature